# Getting NullPointerException in Seam when trying to get ResponseWriter from FacesContext

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I am working on a Seam app. I am trying to get the ResponseWriter from the FacesContext, but I get a `NullPointerException`.

I can get a FacesContext by calling

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
```

According to the debugger, the responseWriter variable in the FacesContext object is null, so calling

```
ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
```

gives a `NullPointerException`.

Why would the ResponseWriter be null? Is it null by default? We can get it from a FacesContext in plenty of other places in our code.

Is there a way I can set it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar to the problem I was getting recently. I tried to use the Excel-writing api within Seam to programmatically generate an Excel file, rather than using an xhtml template with specific tags.

While this worked in older versions of Seam, using the 2.2.0 meant that I couldn't get a Writer from the context to pass to the constructor of the Workbook.

Sadly, I never found a solution, so I'm not sure there is a solution to this.

Comment: Thanks for the response anyway.